# How to make a certain bash script execute when I enter a certain directory?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, directory

I have multiple projects, say, in Python. In each project I have "scripts/main_script.sh". Is there any way to make  "scripts/main_script.sh" execute **automatically** when I go to the base directory of a project?

Namely, when I do `cd /home/my_name/python_project123`, the script `/home/my_name/python_project123/scripts/main_script.sh` should execute automatically.

Comment: only once, or every time you `cd` there?

Comment: @JeffSchaller both, depending on my choise. but at least one of them.

Comment: @JeffSchaller where should I put that script into?

Comment: I'd suggest ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc